# Context inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I m trying to set a "recyclerview" inside a fragment of a bottomnavigation.

```
 mExampleAdapter = new SearchItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
```

Context works for a normal activity. But it does not in this fragment.
I read the documentation which suggest using getActivity() for Context but it doesnt work ?.

```
 mExampleAdapter = new SearchItemAdapter(MainActivity.getActivity(), mExampleList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
```

Comment: It's just `getActivity()`. Don't call it on `MainActivity`. You call it on the current `Fragment` instance.

Comment: thx . that helped

Answer (score 0):

```
mExampleAdapter = new SearchItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mExampleList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
```